# How to send multiple attachments using formhandler

Tags: php

How do i send multiple attachments on a form using this file? The problem im having is that when i fill out the form and send it, i do recive the email but i put in 4 attachments and only recive one. I have been trying for ages now, but still can't figure it out. But luckily i think im on the right path. Thanking you in advance. Hoping you guys can resolve this. You're the best! If you want to see more of the files let me know, i'll send them too.
This is the php file:

```
<?php
namespace FormGuide\Handlx;
use FormGuide\PHPFormValidator\FormValidator;
use PHPMailer;
use FormGuide\Handlx\Microtemplate;
use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;

/**
 * FormHandler 
 *  A wrapper class that handles common form handling tasks
 *      - handles Form validations using PHPFormValidator class
 *      - sends email using PHPMailer 
 *      - can handle captcha validation
 *      - can handle file uploads and attaching the upload to email
 *      
 *  ==== Sample usage ====
 *   $fh = FormHandler::create()->validate(function($validator)
 *          {
 *              $validator->fields(['name','email'])
 *                        ->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
 *              $validator->field('email')->isEmail();
 *              
 *           })->useMailTemplate(__DIR__.'/templ/email.php')
 *           ->sendEmailTo('you@website.com');
 *           
 *   $fh->process($_POST);
 */
class FormHandler
{
    private $emails;
    public $validator;
    private $mailer;
    private $mail_template;
    private $captcha;
    private $attachments;
    private $recaptcha;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = array();
        $this->validator = FormValidator::create();
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail_template='';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact Form Submission ";

        $host = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']:'localhost';
        $from_email ='forms@'.$host;
        $this->mailer->setFrom($from_email,'Contact Form',false);  

        $this->captcha = false;   

        $this->attachments = [];

        $this->recaptcha =null;


    }

    /**
     * sendEmailTo: add a recipient email address
     * @param  string/array $email_s one or more emails. If more than one emails, pass the emails as array
     * @return The form handler object itself so that the methods can be chained
     */
    public function sendEmailTo($email_s)
    {
        if(is_array($email_s))
        {
            $this->emails =array_merge($this->emails, $email_s);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->emails[] = $email_s; 
        }
        
        return $this;
    }

    public function useMailTemplate($templ_path)
    {
        $this->mail_template = $templ_path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [attachFiles find the file uplods and attach to the email]
     * @param  array $fields The array of field names
      */
    public function attachFiles($fields)
    {
        $this->attachments = array_merge($this->attachments, $fields);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipients()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    /**
     * [validate add Validations. This function takes a call back function which receives the PHPFormValidator object]
     * @param  function $validator_fn The funtion gets a validator parameter using which, you can add validations 
     */
    public function validate($validator_fn)
    {
        $validator_fn($this->validator);
        return $this;
    }

    public function requireReCaptcha($config_fn=null)
    {
        $this->recaptcha = new ReCaptchaValidator();
        $this->recaptcha->enable(true);
        if($config_fn)
        {
            $config_fn($this->recaptcha);   
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getReCaptcha()
    {
        return $this->recaptcha;
    }

    public function requireCaptcha($enable=true)
    {
        $this->captcha = $enable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    public function configMailer($mailconfig_fn)
    {
        $mailconfig_fn($this->mailer);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMailer()
    {
        return $this->mailer;
    }

    public static function create()
    {
        return new FormHandler();
    }

    public function process($post_data)
    {
        if($this->captcha === true)
        {
            $res = $this->validate_captcha($post_data);
            if($res !== true)
            {
                return $res;
            }
        }
        if($this->recaptcha !== null &&
           $this->recaptcha->isEnabled())
        {
            if($this->recaptcha->validate() !== true)
            {
                return json_encode([
                'result'=>'recaptcha_validation_failed',
                'errors'=>['captcha'=>'ReCaptcha Validation Failed.']
                ]);
            }
        }

        $this->validator->test($post_data);

        //if(false == $this->validator->test($post_data))
        if($this->validator->hasErrors())
        {
            return json_encode([
                'result'=>'validation_failed',
                'errors'=>$this->validator->getErrors(/*associative*/ true)
                ]);
        }

        if(!empty($this->emails))
        {
            foreach($this->emails as $email)
            {
                $this->mailer->addAddress($email);
            }
            $this->compose_mail($post_data);

            if(!empty($this->attachments))
            {
                $this->attach_files();
            }

            if(!$this->mailer->send())
            {
                return json_encode([
                    'result'=>'error_sending_email',
                    'errors'=> ['mail'=> $this->mailer->ErrorInfo]
                    ]);         
            }
        }
        
        return json_encode(['result'=>'success']);
    }

    private function validate_captcha($post)
    {
        @session_start();
        if(empty($post['captcha']))
        {
            return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code not entered']
                        ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $usercaptcha = trim($post['captcha']);

            if($_SESSION['user_phrase'] !== $usercaptcha)
            {
                return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code does not match']
                        ]);     
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private function attach_files()
    {
        
        foreach($this->attachments as $file_field)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($file_field, $_FILES))
            {
                continue;
            }
            $filename = $_FILES[$file_field]['name'];

            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($filename));

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], 
                $uploadfile))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $this->mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        }
    }

    private function compose_mail($post)
    {
        $content = "Form submission: \n\n";
        foreach($post as $name=>$value)
        {
            $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
            $content .= "$value\n\n";
        }
        $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: The attachFiles function lets you give it an array of field names (i.e. the names of `input type="file"` fields from your HTML form) from which it will get attachments. So that seems to be the solution. What specific problem are you having? You've posted this library code, but not your attempt to use or a clear description of what went wrong when you tried.

Comment: It's just a wrapper round PHPMailer though, which you could easily use directly if you prefer.