# PHP form won't submit with attached files

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm currently running a PHP form script that allows users to upload their resume. The form works when you submit text fields only. But the form stops working when you attach a file. I'm not sure where the error is happening within the code.

## PHP

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'experience'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();


$pp->attachFiles(['resume']);


$pp->sendEmailTo(''); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

## Javascript

```
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data) 
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
            {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if(label)
                {
                    $btn.prop('type','submit' ); 
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                }
            });
            
        }//else
    }

    $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
            $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });
        

                    var formdata = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'handler.php',
                data: formdata,
                success: after_form_submitted,
                dataType: 'json' ,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false        
            });
        
      });   
});
```

## FormHandler.php

```
<?php
namespace FormGuide\Handlx;
use FormGuide\PHPFormValidator\FormValidator;
use PHPMailer;
use FormGuide\Handlx\Microtemplate;
use Gregwar\Captcha\CaptchaBuilder;

/**
 * FormHandler 
 *  A wrapper class that handles common form handling tasks
 *      - handles Form validations using PHPFormValidator class
 *      - sends email using PHPMailer 
 *      - can handle captcha validation
 *      - can handle file uploads and attaching the upload to email
 *      
 *  ==== Sample usage ====
 *   $fh = FormHandler::create()->validate(function($validator)
 *          {
 *              $validator->fields(['name','email'])
 *                        ->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
 *              $validator->field('email')->isEmail();
 *              
 *           })->useMailTemplate(__DIR__.'/templ/email.php')
 *           ->sendEmailTo('you@website.com');
 *           
 *   $fh->process($_POST);
 */
class FormHandler
{
    private $emails;
    public $validator;
    private $mailer;
    private $mail_template;
    private $captcha;
    private $attachments;
    private $recaptcha;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = array();
        $this->validator = FormValidator::create();
        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail_template='';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact Form Submission ";

        $host = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']:'localhost';
        $from_email ='forms@'.$host;
        $this->mailer->setFrom($from_email,'Contact Form',false);  

        $this->captcha = false;   

        $this->attachments = [];

        $this->recaptcha =null;


    }

    /**
     * sendEmailTo: add a recipient email address
     * @param  string/array $email_s one or more emails. If more than one emails, pass the emails as array
     * @return The form handler object itself so that the methods can be chained
     */
    public function sendEmailTo($email_s)
    {
        if(is_array($email_s))
        {
            $this->emails =array_merge($this->emails, $email_s);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->emails[] = $email_s; 
        }
        
        return $this;
    }

    public function useMailTemplate($templ_path)
    {
        $this->mail_template = $templ_path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [attachFiles find the file uplods and attach to the email]
     * @param  array $fields The array of field names
      */
    public function attachFiles($fields)
    {
        $this->attachments = array_merge($this->attachments, $fields);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipients()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    /**
     * [validate add Validations. This function takes a call back function which receives the PHPFormValidator object]
     * @param  function $validator_fn The funtion gets a validator parameter using which, you can add validations 
     */
    public function validate($validator_fn)
    {
        $validator_fn($this->validator);
        return $this;
    }

    public function requireReCaptcha($config_fn=null)
    {
        $this->recaptcha = new ReCaptchaValidator();
        $this->recaptcha->enable(true);
        if($config_fn)
        {
            $config_fn($this->recaptcha);   
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getReCaptcha()
    {
        return $this->recaptcha;
    }

    public function requireCaptcha($enable=true)
    {
        $this->captcha = $enable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    public function configMailer($mailconfig_fn)
    {
        $mailconfig_fn($this->mailer);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMailer()
    {
        return $this->mailer;
    }

    public static function create()
    {
        return new FormHandler();
    }

    public function process($post_data)
    {
        if($this->captcha === true)
        {
            $res = $this->validate_captcha($post_data);
            if($res !== true)
            {
                return $res;
            }
        }
        if($this->recaptcha !== null &&
           $this->recaptcha->isEnabled())
        {
            if($this->recaptcha->validate() !== true)
            {
                return json_encode([
                'result'=>'recaptcha_validation_failed',
                'errors'=>['captcha'=>'ReCaptcha Validation Failed.']
                ]);
            }
        }

        $this->validator->test($post_data);

        //if(false == $this->validator->test($post_data))
        if($this->validator->hasErrors())
        {
            return json_encode([
                'result'=>'validation_failed',
                'errors'=>$this->validator->getErrors(/*associative*/ true)
                ]);
        }

        if(!empty($this->emails))
        {
            foreach($this->emails as $email)
            {
                $this->mailer->addAddress($email);
            }
            $this->compose_mail($post_data);

            if(!empty($this->attachments))
            {
                $this->attach_files();
            }

            if(!$this->mailer->send())
            {
                return json_encode([
                    'result'=>'error_sending_email',
                    'errors'=> ['mail'=> $this->mailer->ErrorInfo]
                    ]);         
            }
        }
        
        return json_encode(['result'=>'success']);
    }

    private function validate_captcha($post)
    {
        @session_start();
        if(empty($post['captcha']))
        {
            return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code not entered']
                        ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $usercaptcha = trim($post['captcha']);

            if($_SESSION['user_phrase'] !== $usercaptcha)
            {
                return json_encode([
                        'result'=>'captcha_error',
                        'errors'=>['captcha'=>'Captcha code does not match']
                        ]);     
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private function attach_files()
    {
        
        foreach($this->attachments as $file_field)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($file_field, $_FILES))
            {
                continue;
            }
            $filename = $_FILES[$file_field]['name'];

            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($filename));

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], 
                $uploadfile))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $this->mailer->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        }
    }

    private function compose_mail($post)
    {
        $content = "Resume submission from careers landing page: \n\n";
        foreach($post as $name=>$value)
        {
            $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
            $content .= "$value\n\n";
        }
        $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
    }
}
```

I updated the code which lead to more errors.

Comment: Is there an html form? What is the `enctype`?

Comment: Yes '<form class="inline-form row" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">'

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of FormHandler?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I can share the js script

Comment: There's no JavaScript, just PHP.

Comment: Note that files are not in `$_POST`, they're in `$_FILES`. So I don't see how `$pp->process($_POST)` could get the uploaded file.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in the `fields` method for the 'lastname' field.

Comment: I found the source code of this class in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119617/how-to-send-multiple-attachments-using-formhandler. Assuming you have `<input type="file" name="resume">` your code should work. The use of `$_FILES` is hard-coded into the method.

Comment: @Barmar  I do have `<input type="file" name="resume">` when I submit the form without the attachment it works fine. But breaks when I attach a file.

Comment: Breaks in what way? Is there an error message in the PHP log?

Comment: The form won't submit. It hangs when you click the submit button.

Comment: If you are only interested in getting it to work, not too concerned with figuring out where you went wrong, try the [Heyageek FileUpload plugin](https://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php). Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Barmar the form is submitting with the attachment. The issue is when I submit the form with an attachment the user doesn't see the sent message after.

Comment: First you said it won't submit, then you said it is submitting. Which is it? Hav eyou tried `var_dump($_FILES);` to see if PHP is receiving the upload?

Comment: None of the autoloader stuff is relevant, that's just composer-generated boilerplate.

Comment: @Barmar what else would be relevant to add for this issue? I thought because the form submit button was stuck on 'SENDING' that the form didn't go through. But I saw all the test attachments in my email.

Comment: What's relevant is the FormHandler class, since it's not standard PHP. Or a link to the github repo.

Comment: @Barmar I added the version of the FormHandler.php I'm using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256563/discussion-between-barmar-and-unohoo).

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate your time and help with this. I think I'm going to go in a different direction. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has occurred when submitting the form from Ajax make sure the form has contain attribute of **enctype="multipart/form-data"** and check the Ajax code has given below:

```
var form = $('#reused_form');
    url = 'handler.php';
    formData = new FormData(form[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data', // <-- add this line in ajax
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: I update the code with what you provided. And the form still hangs when submitting with an attachment.